# Criar array em php, guardando quantas vezes uma string aparece

Tags: php, array

Bom Dia!
Estou com um problema, eu tenho duas strings $procurar e $nome_das_maquinas, dentro de procurar eu tenho o texto completo, e dentro de $nome_das_maquinas as palavras que eu desejo procurar na variável $procurar.

Ex dos valores da variável:

```
$procurar = "Nome da Maquina: Cavadeira, Linha: 1, Gravidade: Média, Operador:Rafael; Nome da Maquina: Cavadeira, Linha: 3, Gravidade: Baixa, Operador:Lucas; Nome da Maquina: Motoniveladora, Linha: 3, Gravidade: Alta, Operador:Joao; Nome da Maquina: Cavadeira, Linha: 1, Gravidade: Média, Operador:Rafael;"

$nome_das_maquinas = "Cavadeira/Cavadeira/Motoniveladora/Cavadeira"
```

Eu preciso contar quantas vezes esses $nomes_das_maquinas aparecem em $procurar e guardar dentro de um array em ordem decrescente

Ex:

```
Cavadeira = 3 <br>
Motoniveladora = 1
```

Estou a alguns dias tentando fazer isso, alguém pode dar um help? Segue meu código de teste:

```
$arquivo = 'arquivos/etiqueta.txt';

$nomedasmaquinas = 'arquivos/nomedasmaquinas.txt';

$handle = fopen( $arquivo, 'r' );

$handle2 = fopen( $nomedasmaquinas, 'r' );

$ler = fread( $handle, filesize($arquivo) );
$ler2 = fread( $handle2, filesize($nomedasmaquinas) );

$procurar = $ler; //Esta vindo de um arquivo que contem as informacoes das maquinas, como um texto 
longo (EX: Nome da maquina: Cavadeira Linha: 1 Gravidade: Media etc...)
$nome_das_maquinas_str = $ler2; //Esta vindo de um arquivo, e as palavras estão separadas por /

$array = explode('/', $nomestr); //Separo as palavras por / e gravo no array
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $valores){
   if($valores){
      $quantidade_que_aparece = substr_count($procurar, $valores); //Conto quantas vezes os valores que estavam no $array aparecem.
       $nomes_vetor[$i] = $quantidade_que_aparece; //Gravo a quantidade em um vetor
   }
  $i++; //Conta +1 pra percorrer o vetor
 }


// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: E qual erro dá @Lucas?

Comment: Erro não dá nenhum, só não consigo pensar nessa solução "Eu preciso contar quantas vezes esses $nomes_das_maquinas aparecem em $procurar e guardar dentro de um array em ordem decrescente"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, seu código está praticamente pronto, só faltou ordenar o array. Fiz as seguintes modificações:

- `$nomestr` não existe, substitui por `$nome_das_maquinas_str`
- Substitui o índice numérico $i pelo nome da máquina.
- `$valores` virou `$maquina`
- Ordenei o array com [`arsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php)

```
<?php
$arquivo = 'arquivos/etiqueta.txt';

$nomedasmaquinas = 'arquivos/nomedasmaquinas.txt';

$handle = fopen( $arquivo, 'r' );

$handle2 = fopen( $nomedasmaquinas, 'r' );

$ler = fread( $handle, filesize($arquivo) );
$ler2 = fread( $handle2, filesize($nomedasmaquinas) );

$procurar = $ler; //Esta vindo de um arquivo que contem as informacoes das maquinas, como um texto longo (EX: Nome da maquina: Cavadeira Linha: 1 Gravidade: Media etc...)
$nome_das_maquinas_str = $ler2; //Esta vindo de um arquivo, e as palavras estão separadas por /

$array = explode('/', $nome_das_maquinas_str); //Separo as palavras por / e gravo no array

foreach($array as $maquina){
    $quantidade_que_aparece = substr_count($procurar, $maquina); //Conto quantas vezes os valores que estavam no $array aparecem.
    $nomes_vetor[$maquina] = $quantidade_que_aparece; //Gravo a quantidade em um vetor
}

//Ordena decrescentemente
arsort($nomes_vetor);

//Exibe
echo "<pre>";var_dump($nomes_vetor);echo "</pre>";

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($handle);
fclose($handle2);
?>
```

Comment: Muitoo obrigado amigo, vou estudar mais arrays em php!

S2